# Выбрать последний id в div блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая структура

```
<div id="block">
  <p id="p_1">text</p>
  <p id="p_2">text</p>
  <p id="p_3">text</p>
  <p id="p_4">text</p>
  ....
</div>
```

Нужно скриптом выдернуть последний id, в примере это p_4, как сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.last()` - Возвращает последний элемент из всех выбранных

[Описание_1](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5)

[Описание_2](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

```js
alert($('#block p').last().attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <p id="p_1">text</p>
  <p id="p_2">text</p>
  <p id="p_3">text</p>
  <p id="p_4">text</p>
</div>
```

Еще вариант:

`:last-child` - Соответствует всем элементам, которые являются последними дочерними объектами у «родителей».

[Описание_1](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

[Описание_2](http://jquery-docs.ru/Selectors/lastChild/)

```js
alert($('#block p:last-child').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
      <p id="p_1">text</p>
      <p id="p_2">text</p>
      <p id="p_3">text</p>
      <p id="p_4">text</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без *jQuery*:

```js
function onClick() {
    var id = document.getElementById("block").lastElementChild.id;
    alert(id);
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <p id="p_1">p_1</p>
  <p id="p_2">p_2</p>
  <p id="p_3">p_3</p>
  <p id="p_4">p_4</p>
</div>
<button onclick="onClick();">Click me!</button>
```